# Angular Dom:- Add missing cells(td) to angular material calendar

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am trying to add missing cells in angular material calendar.
Below is my html

```
<mat-calendar
    [dateClass]="dateClass()"
    [startAt]="month"
    [selected]="selectedDate"
    (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)">
  </mat-calendar>
```

I used ViewChildern to access its dom

```
@ViewChildren(MatCalendar, { read: ElementRef }) calendars: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

I was able to add empty extra row to the bottom of angular material calendar

```
 this.calendars.forEach(calendarEl => {
          const tbody: HTMLElement = calendarEl.nativeElement.querySelector('tbody');

   //ToDO:-- identify last row, count number of cells in last row,if its less than 7  add missing cells

//Added extra row to the bottom

const tr = (document.createElement('tr') as HTMLTableRowElement);
          tr.className = 'date-class';
          for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
          }
          tbody.appendChild(tr);
        });
```

Here is the image of calendar I have without adding missing cells(td). Needed to add 4 more cells
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we do something like getting the last row and add append number of `<td>` to that row so that total count of `<td>` children become 7.

```
let lastRow = calendarEl.nativeElement.querySelector('tbody tr:last-child');
let  vaccantColCount = 7 - lastRow.querySelectorAll('td').length;
console.log(vaccantColCount);
while(vaccantColCount > 0) {
    lastRow.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    vaccantColCount--;
}
```

[image: Final Output]

Comment: I tried it, here is the stackblitz link of working example if you want to try

https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-2sdbdb?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: How you did that? I used same code i was not able to. can you make the change and post the whole code or either fork the stackblitz link and share to me?

Comment: Can you please fork it, it will change the url. Right now, its my code without any chnage. When you click fork, it will create new url for you with your own changes.

Comment: ` ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.calendars.forEach(calendarEl => {
      
      const tbody: HTMLElement = calendarEl.nativeElement.querySelector('tbody');
      let lastRow = calendarEl.nativeElement.querySelector('tbody tr:last-child');
let vaccantColCount = 7 - lastRow.querySelectorAll('td').length;
while(vaccantColCount <= 7) {
   lastRow.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
   vaccantColCount++;
}
      
    });
  }`

This is creating extra rows for feb month

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-dsxx3j  . Sorry for the trouble! Stackblitz was rerendering each time, so i had to quickly windup the code. Cheers